# Possible to hide the search engine indexing disabled prompt/error message?

Tags: errors, options, notifications, search-engines

In Wordpress Settings >> Reading (../wp-admin/options-reading.php) there is an option called "Discourage Search Engines from Indexing This Site". If you check this, a notification error message will nag at you telling your your site cannot be searched by search engines...

*"This site discourages search engines from indexing the pages, which will affect your SEO efforts. You can fix this here"*

Does anyone know how to disable this notification?

I could use css by hiding display of the error class, but I'm afraid it may affect other error messages which may be useful.

Comment: I do not have answer, besides the css solutions, that you might be able to apply for only that page based on body tags... But why disable that message?

Comment: I'd like to disable it because some sites I am building... we do not want it searchable by SEO. Let's say it's for internal use.

Comment: Try to disable the checkbox with javascript instead of css.

Comment: Any suggestions how to do that? I assume you mean using jQuery. The only CSS class selector is the error class which (correct me if I'm wrong) may be shared by other error notifications.